# Django key based session expiration

Tags: django, session, key, django-sessions

I have a website which contains several rule sets for different kind of users.
One of the rules (permission) depends on the session expiration.

For instance, an unauthenticated users' session must be flushed when browser is closed however, authenticated users' sessions should live for a constant time.

Furthermore, for authenticated users some keys in the session may be deleted when the browser is closed but other should be kept alive.

How can I achieve this key-based session expiration in Django ?

Comment: I had a look through the docs. It's easy to expire a particular session after an amount of time, or at browser close, but I can't see any way to do it per key. Hopefully someone else can give you an answer, but you might be forced to create your own implementation of `SessionBase` with per-key expiry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the [`set_expiry`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry) method on `request.session`. The method takes either an integer for number of seconds to expire the session, a `datetime` or `timedelta` for when the session should expire, the integer 0 to indicate the session should expire at browser close time or `None` to indicate that the session should fall-back to the default timeout policy.

You should be able to write a piece of middleware that evaluates the criteria you have for session expiration then call `set_expiry` on the session before processing the request.